# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method script2.js, line 92 character 5

Tags: javascript

Popups work in Firefox and Safari but not in Internet Explorer 9. Using the Dev Tools in Internet Explorer 9, I get the following error (occurs in the function openPopUp).

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   script2.js, line 92 character 5

### Here is <script2.js>

```
var popup_content_cache = '';
var popup_content_src_id = '';
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    console.log("*****NEW******");
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");

    console.log(this.css('top'));
    console.log(parseInt(this.css('top')));
    if (parseInt(this.css('top')) < 0) this.css('top', '20px');

    console.log(parseInt(this.css('top')));
    return this;/*
    this.css("position","absolute");
    var top=($(window).height() - this.outerHeight())/2;

    console.log("top:  " + top)
    console.log($(window).height());
    console.log(this.outerHeight());
    if(top<0){
        console.log("** IF");
        this.css("top", "20px");
        this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +   $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    }
    else {
        this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +
                                                    $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +
                                                    $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    }
    console.log();
    return this;*/
}

function openLayerBC() {
    tWidth = $(document).width();
    tHeight = $(document).height();
    //$("select").fadeOut('fast');
    $('#filter').css("width", tWidth + "px");
    $('#filter').css("height", tHeight + "px");
    // $('#filter').css('z-index',9990);
    $("#filter").css("opacity", 0.8);
    $('#filter').fadeIn('fast');

    //$('#filter').bind("click",closePopup1);
    $('#filter,#close').click(function () {
        $('#filter').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#case_light_box').hide();
        o = document.getElementById('divid');
        o.style.display = o.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    });
}

function closePopup() {
    $('#filter').fadeOut('fast');
    o = document.getElementById('popup');
    o.style.display = 'none';

    // o.style.display = o.style.display=='block'?'none':'block';
    $(o).css("position","absolute");
    $(popup_content_src_id).html(popup_content_cache);
    var popup_content_cache = '';
    var popup_content_src_id = '';
}

function openPopUp(div) {
    openLayerBC();

    div = div.replace('#', '');
    file = div;
    page = '/v/vspfiles/templates/OSS/ajax/products/' + div + '.html';
    $.get(page, {}, function(data)
    {
        msgbox = document.getElementById('popup');
        $(msgbox).html(data);
        $(msgbox).css('width',$('#'+div).css('width'));
        $('#'+div).show();

        $(msgbox).center();
        $(msgbox).show();
    });
}
```

---

This following is the line 92 of <script2.js> the message refers to.

```
 page = '/v/vspfiles/templates/OSS/ajax/products/'+div+'.html';
```

Disclaimer: I inherited this JavaScript code and have little experience myself with JavaScript and its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'var' before 'page':

```
var page = '/v/vspfiles/templates/OSS/ajax/products/'+div+'.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

`page` looks like it might be undefined. Also, it's possible that div or page are not strings.  You can open a developer console, put a `debugger;` statement before the error, and inspect the `div` and `page` variables before the error is thrown to narrow it down.

Comment: You r correct about page being undefined...but it only works intermittently. It works on one machine IE9 but only if F12 Developer Tools has been turned on???

Comment: It's possible that some browsers, in certain modes, are less strict about undefined variables.  They definitely deal with errors in different ways (particularly malformed html).